# ASP.NET Core Identity: How to Use EF Core Transactions?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I use EF Core in my project, and I want to achieve atomicity when using built-in Identity methods (such as `CreateAsync` or `AddClaimsAsync`). Here is my use case:

```
#region CREATE USER & SET ROLE

var newUser = new ApplicationUser
{
    // set user properties here...              
};

var result1 = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser);

var result2 = await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(newUser, new Claim[]{
                new Claim("asSuperUser", "asSuperUser")
});
#endregion

#region SEND ACCOUNT INITIALIZATION EMAIL

if (result1.Succeeded && result2.Succeeded)
{
    // continue if everything went fine...
```

Of course, if all goes well, there is no problem, but what if Identity failed to add claims to the added user (`AddClaimsAsync` method failed)? That would be bad news, because entire project revolves around CBAC (claims-based access control), so ensuring atomicity is crucial here. My question is: is there a way to make use of EF Core transactions when using Identity's built-in methods such as `CreateAsync` or `AddClaimsAsync`, where I'm not directly using the DbContext via DI, but rather using various Identity services (such as `userManager`) thus accessing DbContext indirectly?

Things would get even more complicated if I were using multiple Identity services (such as combining `SignInManager` and `UserManager`, where each scoped service instance would presumably create their own instance of DbContext).

Comment: Just call `SaveChanges` *once* at the very end. There are no EF Core Transactions, EF Core isn't a database driver. EF Core uses the Unit-of-Work pattern anyway. A DbContext keeps track of all changes in memory and persists all of them at the very end, when you call `SaveChanges`, in an internal database transaction

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that would be the case if I were relying on change tracker, which is not the case here. Right? Each Identity service method work on its own and apply changes internally. I am not even accessing DbContext directly here.

Comment: That's the case, period. Identity is storage agnostic and the real store may *not* be a database or not use EF Core. In your case you could wrap the entire code in a [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-7.0). This will enlist all ADO.NET connections in a single long-lived database transaction. Call Commit before going out of scope to commit all changes. This will keep connections open for the duration of the Transactionscope though, along with any locks taken. That causes more blocking and harms scalability

Comment: You need to keep in mind that if the services use different databases, TransactionScope will try to create a distributed transaction. This won't be a problem in *SQL Server* if the databases are stored on the same DB instance. SQL Server will still use a normal cross-database transaction. If the databases are on different servers, or you use different databases though, TransactionScope will start a distributed transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, EF Core transactions can work with Identity service methods. Example:

```
using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

// CREATE USER
var result1 = await userManager.CreateAsync(superUser);
if (!result1.Succeeded)
{
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                var errors1 = result1.Errors.Select(error => error.Description);
                return Json(new { success = false, error = string.Join(", ", errors1) });
}

// ASSIGN RELEVANT ROLE
var result2 = await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(superUser, new Claim[]{
                new Claim("asSuperUser", "asSuperUser")
});
if (!result2.Succeeded)
{
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                var errors2 = result2.Errors.Select(error => error.Description);
                return Json(new { success = false, error = string.Join(", ", errors2) });
}

// await context.SaveChangesAsync(); you would only need this if you relied on change tracker, which is not the case here
await transaction.CommitAsync();

return Json(new { success = true });
```

Comment: That's the "dirty" way I didn't want to post. You can use a TransactionScope instead of trying to access the scope's DbContext explicitly. You don't need any of the `RollBack` calls either, just exit the transaction scope. Disposing a DbTransaction results in a rollback. DbTransacion and DbContext use the same pattern here - unless you explicitly commit, everything is discarded

Comment: You don't need the final `SaveChanges` either, unless you performed any modifications yourself. The very reason you posted this question is that `CreateUserAsync` and `AddClaimsAsync` call `SaveChanges` internally.